# Performing Overlay of Two Triangulated Irregular Networks (TIN)

Tags: geometry, tin

I am referring to the [paper here](http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/gis/TINalg.pdf), section 2.6.1, on the adding and subtracting of two TINs:

> The addition of two TINs can be
>   determined exactly and stored into a
>   new TIN, because the addition of
>   piecewise linear functions again
>   yields a piecewise linear function.
>   The addition is done by **performing an
>   overlay of `T1` and and `T2`**, there
>   are several algorithms for this. After
>   this we obtain a subdivision where all
>   faces have 3,4,5,6 edges. We now must
>   fill in the height information for the
>   vertices of the overlay..

Although I can understand every single word out of the passage, I don't know how to carry out the above procedure in practice to obtain the cut/fill of the two TINs.

More specifically, I would like to know *how to perform the overlay of two TINs*. There are references given at the end of the paper, but I can't have access to them because I'm not inside a university library. So any readily accessible online reference (or code samples) are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can overlay two (vector) polygon layers you can overlay two TINs.  Some discussion of algorithms appears in many places,including

[A Novel Algorithm for Union between Complex Polygons](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5380721/;jsessionid=syK3SQtyRddQYCMVsQSN9I95v9SYmFTv0NXkhHSMTNy68QNoFJZP!78790607)

[Vector Overlay Processing - Specific Theory](https://web.archive.org/web/20091002183242/http://www.geom.unimelb.edu.au/gisweb/VOModule/VO_Theory.pdf)

[A Design for Polygon Overlay Algorithm in the Simple Feature Model](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1109/GCC.2008.41)

[Volumes from overlaying 3-D triangulations in parallel](http://www.springerlink.com/content/7r011530537w2537/)

(Unfortunately, most of these are abstracts, not the actual papers.)  Basic algorithms will appear in any good textbook on computational geometry.  [Plane sweep algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_operations_on_polygons) are an attractive and oft-used choice.  [C++ source code](https://boolean.klaasholwerda.nl/bool.html) is available.